# Responsive Google Ad doesn't show up on my website

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, adsense

I added a responsive Google Ad to our game's website, which is a simple static bootstrap based site:
http://dealoround.com which will resolve to
https://mrcsabatoth.github.io/DealORoundWebsite/

My problem is that no Ad shows up. First I put the Ad code at the end of the HTML. Then I thought that maybe it doesn't show up, because I'm just running the development version of the website from my local machine, but my `AdSense` account doesn't have any restrictions on who can display my ad unit. So I pushed my changes to `GitHub`, but still no luck. Finally I tried to move the code to the footer, also didn't help.

When I inspect the DOM, the `ins` element is there, but hidden. If I say `window.adsbygoogle.push({})` to try to get it alive, nothing changes, but the function returns the value `2`, whatever that means (does anyone know?).

I'm total newbie to AdSense. All helps are welcome.

Comment: Do I have to place the code into specific div (where I want it to be displayed) maybe?

Comment: If I the code to the help page of the website at least the ins element doesn't seem to be hidden, but it's computed height is 0px.

Comment: Had this problem before, and the solution was just pausing the 'AdBlock' extension on Google Chrome that I had enabled. Just make sure it isn't running, otherwise it'll hide your ad completed. See my answer with an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see your ad perfectly, but only after I have paused 'AdBlock' on my browser.

See the below screenshot of your site:

[image]

Here is a short tutorial on how to disable AdBlock - http://www.wikihow.com/Disable-Adblock

Comment: @CsabaToth - Haha, sometimes it's the simple things. Glad I could help.